# Replace bullets with numbering

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, substitution, bulletedlist

I have the following text:

> This is user message
>
> - Message one
> - Message two
> - Message three

where I want to replace all the bullets with numbers:

> This is user message
>
> 1. Message one
> 2. Message two
> 3. Message three

This text in available in only **one** cell of Excel file.

Can anyone suggest a formula to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different formula may suit for a different interpretation:

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","3.",3),"-","2.",2),"-","1.",1)
```

[image: SO26337578 example]

Answer (score -1):

Presuming that the following data starts at A1

- Message one
- Message two
- Message three

On B1 - enter in the following formula and drag it down to copy all cells and remove the bullet point and replace it with nothing.

```
=CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"•",""))
```

Finally, once you have that on B1, copy the entire row and paste it as values. Delete all items from column A  and add the number 1 in A1, 2 in A2 and 3 in A3. Highlight those three items and double click on the bottom right hand corner of last cell.

You will have 2 cells, containing the following

Cell A1 = 1
Cell B1 = Message one

etc..

on Cell C1, type in the following `=A1&" "&B1` and drag it down, should give you the result.

Comment: You could use `ROW()` here, to simplify

Comment: I agree with @CallumDS33 's `ROW()` comment, which makes column C unnecessary.  I thought the `CLEAN` function might be unnecessary, because `SUBSTITUTE` removes the bullet.  But could there be nonprintable characters when a bullet list is pasted into Excel?